# How can I change a character in line every n lines using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Let's say I have this kind of file:

```
         248
 STEP:           1
 C      0.975156      8.208886     -0.860474
 C      1.519935      8.610952      0.374438
 C      1.771419      9.990898      0.592491
 C      1.418414     10.881772     -0.466490

         248
 STEP:           6
 C      0.985225      8.205446     -0.859378
 C      1.520091      8.611807      0.372435
 C      1.775156      9.991095      0.588109
 C      1.415878     10.886006     -0.465814
```

with ~1500000 lines

and I need to have sth like this:

```
         248
 STEP:           1
 C      0.975156      8.208886     -0.860474
 C      1.519935      8.610952      0.374438
 D      1.771419      9.990898      0.592491
 C      1.418414     10.881772     -0.466490

         248
 STEP:           6
 C      0.985225      8.205446     -0.859378
 C      1.520091      8.611807      0.372435
 D      1.775156      9.991095      0.588109
 C      1.415878     10.886006     -0.465814
```

how can I achive this with awk/sed/whatever?

Comment: It's just changing C with D, according to which conditions?

Comment: what changes u want exactly?

Comment: every third C to D. I have this block structure as presented above multiple times and in every block I need to change third C to D

Comment: Do you want to change 'every third C to D' or do you want to change the value of the first column in the third line after the line "STEP:" to C?

Comment: Sorry, William is completely right. I need to change the value of the first column in the third line after the line "STEP:" from C to D.

Comment: Do you need to change the value to "D" because it was "C" or just because it's the third line after STEP? What if the 3rd line after STEP started with B - would you want to change that B to a D or would you want to change the C in the line after that (i.e. the 4th line but the 3rd C line) to D?

Comment: Syntax is always the same for letters, only different numbers in 2nd, 3rd & 4th columns - it's trajectory, so always third line after STEP, but karakfa provided perfect solution :) Nevertheless thank you Ed for your interest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^ STEP/{c=0}  /^ C/ && ++c==3{sub(/C/,"D")}1' file
```

or with count-down

```
$ awk '/^ STEP/{c=3} /^ C/ && !--c{sub(/C/,"D")}1' file
```

if your file doesn't have leading spaces remove them from the patterns as well.  In the posted file above you have them.